# Preposition when speaking about time record

Tags: prepositions, time

I want to say something in meaning of "You've made the record at?/in? 2 seconds" - basically a user answers questions and time to answer is measured. After each question, I want to say if a new record was made and what's the record.

But to be honest neither at/in or other preposition seems to be right and I don't know how an English speaking person would say this. (And something like 'you've made a record, you've answered in X seconds' seem to me a bit awkward.)

Thank you

Comment: Try "You have set a new record ***of*** 2 seconds".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **set a new record** (for speed, distance, whatever).

P.S. And as Billy Kerr remarks in his comment and stangdon does in his answer, to refer to the specifics of the record, you use this pattern:

You have set a new record `of  {number}  {unit of measurement}`

> You have set a new free-diving record of 214 meters!
>
> You have set a new record  of 133 days for being adrift in a raft at
>   sea!

Answer (score 1):

*In X* where X is a duration can be used to express that an activity was completed and the time to completion was X.

*For X* is used if you just want to say how long something lasted or took, without implying completedness.

> I walked to the store in 15 minutes. (15 minutes passed and now I'm at the store.)
>
> I walked to the store for 15 minutes (Sounds weird, did you make it to the store?)
>
> I walked through the park for 15 minutes (There's no "endpoint" we were trying to reach, so this sounds better.)

*At X*, if X is a time, needs to be a clock time, not a duration.  If it's anything but a clock time, *on X* is used.  *On* isn't usually specified if it happens at the beginning of the sentence.

> At 3pm I went to the store.  I went to the store at 3pm.
>
> Wednesday I went to the store.  I went to the store on Wednesday.

Comment: Thank you. If I say "You've made the record in X seconds" and the context is that it's after they answered the question. Doesn't it sound that X seconds is related not only to answering the question but also to doing something to achieve record so 'in' is ambiguous in that sense ? I know 2 seconds are short for that but to me it sounds so but I'm not native ... so I can be wrong - am I ? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to say that there is a new record and the record is a certain amount is "a new record **of** 2 seconds".  For example,

> [H. S. Kehlor driving the Johnson-powered Rowdy set a new record of 44.444 m.p.h.](https://books.google.com/books?id=PfJgN6a-pGsC&pg=PA398&lpg=PA398&dq=%22set%20a%20new%20record%20of%22&source=bl&ots=A3p8Hko9OY&sig=UyzGA_ez9mnWtT7epAWAZ8CrWeA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4ut6nx-LYAhWn7oMKHQzVDKIQ6AEISzAI#v=onepage&q=%22set%20a%20new%20record%20of%22&f=false)
>
> [Ahead of World AIDS Day, Apple says this year’s (RED) purchases set a new record of over $30M](https://9to5mac.com/2017/11/30/apple-red-record-total-value/)
>
> [The Russians set a new record of 114,000 feet...](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/50d36705-9c3d-452a-9fb7-9369d6199438)